# UI Manager for Android outside of Main Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, singleton, fragmentmanager

I'd like to create a "State Manager" class that can handle fragment transactions.

I currently only have a "MainActivity" which extends "AppCompatActivity" and gets an instance of FragmentManager.

Is Fragment Manager a singleton class, and if so, how can I ensure my "StateManager" receives the same singleton of it without extending Fragment?

Comment: FragmentManager is not a singleton, there's a new instance for each activity instance (and also separate FragmentManagers for child fragments)

Comment: @ianhanniballake ah thank you, so would that mean if I want to replace what the current main activity is displaying, I’d need the same instance? Or would a new instance be able to replace the content of the main activities fragment manager as well?